# Websphere application server on Bluemix — install APAR fix

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-was-oc

How can I install an APAR fix (temp fix) to the WAS on Bluemix?
Is there any documentation to teach me how to do it?
I cannot find the installation manager in the Linux OS, but even if I have it, how would I install the fix using ssh mode?

Comment: Is this "websphere as a service"? Or instant runtimes / cloud foundry? Or liberty in docker?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the Installation Manager in the /home/virtuser/IBM/InstallationManager directory [1]. Any fixes must be installed as **virtuser**. Once you're in the appropriate IM directory, it should be business as usual for using the **imcl install** command. The link below should reference additional IM documentation.

[1] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ApplicationServeronCloud/installationConventions.html